# Can you add a collection view in a UIView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add a collection view in a UIview to display users posts like Instagram has where you are able to swipe left and right on a users profile:

Can you add a collection view in the purple bit below (which is a UIView)?

So far this is what I have tried and I am not getting it to work and I'm not sure what else to try

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"


class CollectionView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    //MARK: - Properties
    let cellId = "cellId"

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return view
    }()


    //MARK: - Init

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    
        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    //MARK: - UICollectionView

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
            return 2
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the delegate and data source for your collection view
try this

```
 lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
view.dataSource = self 
view.delegate = self
        return view
    }()
```